# Reg expression in .net to start with 2 specific characters, end with a digit, and at a certain length

Tags: .net, regex

Ok Reg ex experts, I am not very good with regex and am hoping for some help. I have a regular expression that I cannot for the life of me figure out. I am looking to create a regular expression that will match the following:

Starts with a "PA" (ingore case)

Ends with a digit

Is 8 characters long (ignoring any trailing white space)

or

Starts with a "WN" (ingore case)

Ends with a digit

Is 10 characters long (ignoring any trailing white space)

Comment: To be honest I didn't even know where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Trim the whitespace off the ends of your string per requirement
yourString = yourString.Trim();
//Declare regex, the pattern tells it to look for any 7 letter word
//which starts with PA and ends with a digit and is 7 characters long
//OR a word which starts with WN and ends with a digit and is 10 characters long. 
Regex regex = new Regex(^PA.+\d${7})|(^WN.+\d${10});
//Set the regex option to ignore case
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
//Get the match collection by passing your string, the regex pattern and
//the regex options
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(yourString, regex, options);

//Do something with captured text
```

Comment: @d_kennetz Hello, thank you for letting me know about the answer being flagged. I added a lot of comments to explain my answer, please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  The only issue I have is that this will be used in a MVC data attribute so the .IgnoreCase is not possible.  I apologies.  I should have been more specific.  I suppose I can just add another or with the lowercase versions

Comment: @JSON Just comment out the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` line and on the first line where you trim the whitespace, call `ToLower()` as well, so `yourString = yourString.ToLower().Trim();` And, you are welcome for the answer, I hope it helps.